# How to prove that AWS DMS Validation works properly?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I migrated the data using AWS DMS from one database(mysql) to another(postgres) and want to check that the build-in validation feature works properly.

I updated manually one row in the Target database and run "Revalidate". The result is - validated without any errors... Unexpected

I deleted all rows in the target database and the validation showed me that everything is good and 2 databases are in sync.

I read from the [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migration-validation-part-2-introducing-data-validation-in-aws-data-migration-service/)

> If the target database is modified outside of AWS DMS, validation might fail to report the discrepancies accurately.

The main question is how can I prove that the AWS DMS Validation works properly and I can trust it?